# using integer to call different strings

Tags: java, compiler-construction

im trying to to make a DOS game or System.out.print and using interfaces.. but i can't know how .. awwww .. i mean like when the Character gets hurt saying different Sentences by using Random methods amm 
like the code in here

```
String sh1 = "";
String sh2 = "";
String sh3 = "";
Random r1 = new Random(); 
int ir1 = r1.nextInt(3)+1;
int ih1 = 1;
int ih2 = 2;
int ih3 = 3;
integer.ToString(ih1);
integer.ToString(ih2);
integer.ToString(ih3);
```

i hope i explained enough to be understand sorry if there's any mistake i'm here to learn 
and thanks for understanding

Comment: explain the question better . and do you need random int or String ? question and code seem to contradict each other

Answer (score 3):

This is where you use *arrays*:

```
String[] sh = {
    "First sentence",
    "Second sentence",
    "Third sentence"
};
int ir1 = r1.nextInt(sh.length);
System.out.println(sh[ir1]);
```

Note that the array indexes start with `0`.

Comment: +1 A good time to learn basic Java constructs I suspect.